# Inserting all elements from a "n"x3 array from (1 to n,3) into a single string variable

Tags: arrays, vba, element

I have an array "cupcakes" that is n elements long and 3 elements wide.

I want to populate a variable "quark" with the string of elements from cupcakes that is like...
cupcakes(1,3) & cupcakes(2,3) & "cupcakes(3,3) &... cupcakes(n,3)

So where n=4 and

cupcakes(1,3)=B

cupcakes(2,3)=A

cupcakes(3,3)=B

cupcakes(4,3)=C

... quark would be equal to "BABC"

I currently have

```
For n = 1 To kount - 1
quark = cupcakes(n, 3)
Next n
```

but this just changes quark to the next value in the cupcakes array instead of making it go like cupcakes(1,3) & cupcakes(2,3) &...

How can I edit this code? I appreciate your help!

Comment: What's stopping you from just coding that?  That's a pretty basic `For...Next` loop and use of `&` - try it out.

Comment: I've figured out how implement only Do... Loop Until loops so far. So would it be like `For each n in cupcakes quark equals index(cupcakes(n,3)' ?`
Sorry If I seem clueless I am self-taught with no training or background outside of this project in VBA.

Comment: `For i=lbound(cupcakes,1) to ubound(cupcakes,1):s=s & cupcakes(i,3)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to put multiple elements into a string utilize the **For... Next Loop**

```
dim quark as string
for i=lbound(cupcakes,1) to ubound(cupcakes,1)
quark=quark & cupcakes(i,3)
next i
```